# Pagination with backbone.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I would like to implement a pagination to this simple [web app](https://github.com/thomasdavis/backbonetutorials/tree/gh-pages/examples/todo-app).

I see that is possible to use [backbone.paginator](https://github.com/addyosmani/backbone.paginator), but before to use this component, I would like to know what is the simplest and cleanest way to implement a pagination with backbone.js.

Here a little of code:
please see the comments in the AppView

---

> **The view**

```
var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
         items.fetch(); // <-- now it fetches all the data, 
                        //     I would like to set a limit
    }
});
```

---

**The collection**

```
var ItemsCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
     model: item
```

---

**The model**

```
var ItemModel = Backbone.Collection.extend({
     return ItemModel;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `items.fetch()`, use something like `items.fetchPage({pageSize: 12, pageNumber: 23})` then implement this as a method on the collection.